# Removing non-English words from text using Python

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning

I am doing a data cleaning exercise on python and the text that I am cleaning contains Italian words which I would like to remove. I have been searching online whether I would be able to do this on Python using a tool kit like nltk.

For example given some text :

```
"Io andiamo to the beach with my amico."
```

I would like to be left with :

```
"to the beach with my"
```

Does anyone know of a way as to how this could be done?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `words` corpus from NLTK:

```
import nltk
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = "Io andiamo to the beach with my amico."
" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \
         if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
# 'Io to the beach with my'
```

Unfortunately, *Io* happens to be an English word. In general, it may be hard to decide whether a word is English or not.

Comment: Edited to preserve non-words (punctuation, numbers, etc.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but when I applied the plural form of noun. Such as resources, boys. It was also removed. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: The words corpus does not contain the plural forms. You have to do lemmatization first.

Comment: Add the line: `nltk.download('words')` if you are getting `Resource words not found.`.

Comment: @DYZ is there a way to use `words` corpus on a column of `array<string>` ? Please view my questions [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367953/remove-non-english-words-from-column-in-pyspark) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430946/remove-meaningless-words-from-pyspark-column)

Comment: Hey but the nltk corpus words is not exhaustive in nature, it does not contain all the different forms of a word, synonyms of a word, etc... :/ it only contains 235886 unique English words. I tried to check if the word company and companies both exists in this set. I only found company and not companies. Considering this, is there a way to increase the size of the set with more words, different forms and synonyms of the same word? or is there another efficient way to go about this?

Comment: @sachinkimars You can do lemmatization before looking up the words in the corpus.

Answer (score 5):

In MAC OSX it still can show an exception if you try this code. So make sure you download the words corpus manually. Once you `import` your `nltk` library, make you might as in mac os it does not download the words corpus automatically. So you have to download it potentially otherwise you will face exception.

```
import nltk 
nltk.download('words')
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
```

Now you can perform same execution as previous person directed.

```
sent = "Io andiamo to the beach with my amico."
sent = " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

According to [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/data.html) documentation it doesn't say so. But I got a [issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2357) over github and solved that way and it really works. If you don't put the `word`  parameter there, you OSX can logg off and happen again and again.

Comment: Hey but the nltk corpus words is not exhaustive in nature, it does not contain all the different forms of a word, synonyms of a word, etc... :/ it only contains 235886 unique English words. I tried to check if the word company and companies both exists in this set. I only found company and not companies. Considering this, is there a way to increase the size of the set with more words, different forms and synonyms of the same word? or is there another efficient way to go about this?

Comment: This is where stemming words come in. You can use NLTK to take words back to their root word. for example [ 'cared', 'caring', 'careful'] are all stemmed down to care. You can check the SnowballStemmer

Answer (score -1):

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

snow_stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')
  
#list of words
words = ['cared', 'caring', 'careful']
  
#stem of each word
stem_words = []
for w in words:
    x = snow_stemmer.stem(w)
    stem_words.append(x)
      
#stemming results
for w1,s1 in zip(words,stem_words):
    print(w1+' ----> '+s1)
```