# What's the best way to remove foreign words in review for topic extraction?

Tags: python, text-mining

This question actually has two parts, whether removing foreign words is necessary and what's the best way to realise it.

I'm a beginner trying to extract topics from English food review basically using latent dirchlet allocation in Python. The output is 5 topics each with 50 words each, and I have used NLTK to remove English stopwords.
But one (and only one) topic contains many foreign words that might not bear meanings, like "de" "la" "et" "les".

Some original reviews that contain these words:

`-A la carte sushi is great. Pot of soup is huge and delicious.
-I would be interested in returning to try their Anticuchos, Ceviche de Mixto, Cau Cau, Aji de Gallina, and Chaufa de Camaron.
-I recommend patients in the parking lot. I would be lying if I didn't admit its some of the finest que in the country!`

The next step is get user vector, item vector and train, test, validate the results.

Are these words meaningful, or shall they be removed?

And how to remove the words?

One answer in the question below suggests using NLKT set of English words, but I found the words set quite small, and words like "de" "un" cannot be removed.

```
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
len(words) #235892
```

Another method suggest python package enchanted but it's not maintained anymore.

[Removing non-English words from text using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290028/removing-non-english-words-from-text-using-python)

The topic results I got are:

`pizza  burger  cheese  de  good    place   crust   sauce   burgers     order   et  service     toppings    pizzas  like    la  fresh   le  thin    restaurant  un  slice   best    great   delivery    time    pour    poutine     delicious   garlic  menu    try     pepperoni   est     taste   back    les     sandwich    meat    food    better  style   fast    plus    minutes     que     little  pie     onion   pas`

Comment: Natural language processing is never-ending problem in IT. There some solution however. I am able to give you two hints: forget about removing it by words. Use set of worlds. There are single words that have meaning in many languages, that's why you should not remove `a` but try to find `a la carte`.
Second hint is for you to profile your texts and select only words which occurs the most.
But those might not be the best solutions :)