# How to find and remove invalid / meaningless text in python?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, corpus

I want to remove meaningless or invalid data on cell.
(A combination of meaningless alphabets or only numbers in cells)

**My data is below.**

```
ID         A1           B1          C1
1          apple        adfs        banana
2          I love you   mom         111
3          zaaaaf       dad         348080
```

**Expected output as below.**

```
ID         A1           B1          C1
1          apple                    banana
2          I love you   mom         
3                       dad
```

How can I this?

Comment: Nice set of tags. The only thing used (from the output) I can see is maybe python/pandas. Did you actually try to solve this using any of them? [mre] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare values to some dictonary, here from `ntlk` and if not match remove values, but still is possible some values are removed like `mom` if not exist in dictionary ntlk:

```
import nltk
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/41290205
f = lambda x: " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(x) if w.lower() in words)

#apply only for object columns (obviously strings)
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(f)
print (df)
   ID          A1   B1      C1
0   1       apple       banana
1   2  I love you             
2   3              dad
```

Comment: @jezrael I ran your code but occurred  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @purplecollar - It seems some data related problem, are data confidental?

Comment: @jezrael type of columns are object and there are many blank columns. Also, many columns has sentence value.

Comment: @purplecollar - Can you test if values are strings? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574)

Comment: @purplecollar - Another idea, how working `df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('').applymap(f)` ?

Comment: @jezrael okay, I will try your solutions and then leave  feedback